# Forcing different CSS styles to override the existing adf styling

Tags: javascript, css, oracle-adf

I am using ADF technology for my website. But for a single select table, I am not able to change the on hover background color to a color that I require using CSS. Is there any way I can change it using JavaScript?

Comment: Please are you able to provide some of the html you wish to change? JS Fiddle or link to site?

Comment: Actually the HTML code already has a background color style set for every row.. I would like to know how I can change this color when a particular row is selected.. I tried using CSS but the HTML style overrides the CSS Style. Is there any way I can Force a different style using javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment above:

you can change the style of an element doign this:

```
$('#ElementIId).css('background-color','red')
```

Now in your case, if you want to change the hover effect of an element you can do this:

```
// Note oyu can also use a class selector $(".myclass").hover...
$("#ElementIId").hover(function(e) 
{  
  $(this).css("background-color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"red":"transparent") 
});
```

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please accept my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is skinning. Skins has class support for all adf-components. And skins have its own rules to rule the components look and feel.

You can google for ADF Skinning guide or just [read this comprehensive article](https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/how_to_learn_adf_skinning)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard coding the style in the JSF page you might want to consider externalizing it to a skin css file which would make it easier to maintain.
Here is a demo of how to do that - 
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/styling_specific_adf_components_with